# What other than programming does a computer science degree usually involve?

Tags: programming-languages

Programming courses are about 30% of my computer science degree. Also at my university, around 15-20% of the degree are applied math courses.

What other areas/fields are covered? For the majority of ABET accredited universities?

The question that inspired this post was "should i study computer science if I'm only interested in programming at this point?"

Comment: Accreditation usually leads to broadly similar course structures, so why not look at a few? Also, the [Wikipedia page on CS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_science) lists the main areas of the field as a whole.

Comment: Why, um, _all_ the things? (I'd argue that if you have 30% programming, you're not getting a computer _science_ degree. So let's hope that they call it programming but actually teach you different things.)

Answer (score 0):

A computer science education, among answering a lot of "how?" questions, also covers areas whose purpose is to answer most of the "why?" questions. Those are, in my opinion, the most important, mind-opening and motivating for a future computer scientist with a programming background:

- [Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic)
- [Computer Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture)
- [Computability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory)
- [Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory)
- [Machine Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) and [Artificial Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) (which are very closely related and are a part of applied math, which you mentioned. These are of great importance on today's market)

**see comments** for more examples.

Those will give your programming skills a major boost, enrich you with deeper understanding of what's behind the lines of code and thus give you a great advantage when applying for a future job in this area.

Should you study computer science if you are now interested only in programming? I think absolutely yes. You will not lack programming courses for sure, so that's a plus already. Also, you will learn many more interesting things about programming that maybe you haven't yet encountered to figure out that you are interested in them.

Comment: While those are indeed components of a typical CS course, there are many other aspects, too. I'm not sure it's really representative to pull out those four areas as being somehow the most important: what's important varies a lot depending on a person's interests and goals. Most of the research funding in the UK at the moment seems to be for machine learning and big data, so they seem pretty important, and also very relevant to somebody who wants a programming career.

Comment: I agree that it depends on personal interest, but the question was what else is a part of CS education beside what @kanayt already mentioned (programming and applied math). I would categorize machine learning as applied math so I didn't list it, but it really is of massive influence now-days and I will add it to the list.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  ,but why the downvote!  However,the answer forgets to mention;  *distributedComputing*  which is kinda broad just like AI.

Comment: @quintumnia And algorithms, data structures, compilers, graphics, operating systems, ... I think I explained my reasoning quite clearly.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  ,I copy that. The OP should as well go digging  deeper...Networks.etc.

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for your efforts! Please note that we closed the question because it's not suited for this platform; you may want to develop a nose for such things in order not to waste your time in the future.

Comment: @Raphael may be the question should be moved to https://academia.stackexchange.com/ ?  I think that the question by itself is completely valid, it just may be wrong for *this* site.

Comment: If you put in ML and AI, you need to put in a lot of other applied branches like Databases, Computer Graphics, Compilers, Cryptography, whatever. You can't say that everything in CS depends on ML and AI like it depends on mathematical logic. I would add Programming Language Semantics and Program Verification to the foundation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  “[ML] really is of massive influence now-days and I will add it to the list” The key word is “now-days”. Fads come and go.

Comment: @Bulat My feeling is that the question isn't really on-topic at academia, either. Most features of undergraduate life are off-topic there. Questions about how to _design_ a syllabus are on-topic but questions about what a typical syllabus looks like will most likely be met, as here, with "Go look at a few and find out."

Comment: @beroal But the question isn't about identifying the core foundations of CS on which everything else depends; it's about what's in a typical (US) CS syllabus. And a typical CS syllabus contains all the extra things that we've mentioned that weren't included in this answer, plus a whole lot more.